# Slow wifi with "R8188EU" driver in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers

Im new to ubuntu, i have dual boot in my ssd with both win10 and ubuntu, my TP-LINK dongle works fine in win, but in ubuntu i have 100kb/s max download speed, which is nothing, i didnt need to install any drivers, when i plug the dongle i guess ubuntu downloaded the driver and i had wifi, tried many things of older posts but couldn't find someone with the same problem, now im trying update some drivers but since download speed is 100kb im posting this to see if i can find another way to tackle the issue, since i almost know nothing please ask me if you need specific information, signal strength is excellent, link speed is 72mb/s whatever that means.. Here is some information.
Hope anyone can help me, thanks! This is what i already tried :[Install driver from github](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-tp-link-wifi-adapter-driver-in-linux),added 50kb/s more of download speed lol but definitely not the solution. Also tried changing ipv6, disabling wifi powersave, changed a lot of things, tried almost everything from all the posts i could find, even the ethernet downgrade. I readed that the ethernet driver r8169 isnt very good, that i should use r8168, but can ethernet drivers mess with the wifi driver? im not sure how that works

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:9c:23:99:ba:d3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df104000-df104fff memory:df100000-df103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlx18d6c70b2c17
       serial: 18:d6:c7:0b:2c:17
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic ip=192.168.0.192 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn.
```

Comment: which dongle do you have (model name/number)?

Comment: the model is TP-Link TL-WN723N